# Python: Continue past a "RuntimeError" when looping through data

Tags: python, for-loop, exception, try-catch, continue

How would I go about continueing past a RuntimeError when looping through a list of data?
For example lets say I have function f as below:

```
t_ints = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
 
def f(x):
    for i in x:
        if i==3:
            continue
        
        elif i ==6:
            raise RuntimeError('NOP')
        print(f'Processing integer {i}')
    
    print("Done")
    return

f(t_ints)
```

The function will print each number except 3, passes three and continues to 4. However when it reaches 6 it will yield a RunTimeError I titled NOP. So the output is:

```
Processing integer 1
Processing integer 2
Processing integer 4
Processing integer 5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\jalmendarez.MSQT\Visual Studio Code\Test Notebooks\Test Sheet 1.py in 
     251     return
     252 
---> 253 f(t_ints)

c:\Users\jalmendarez.MSQT\Visual Studio Code\Test Notebooks\Test Sheet 1.py in f(x)
      245 
      246         elif i ==6:
----> 247             raise RuntimeError('NOP')
     248         print(f'Processing integer {i}')
     249 

RuntimeError: NOP
```

I want to pass of list of  integers like t_ints above, and apply the function in for loop to each list.

```
z=[
    [11, 22, 33, 3, 55, 66, 87, 8, 9, 10],
    [31, 3, 53, 54, 3, 66, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [2,4,6,8,10,11,35]
]
```

So I coded the below in to loop through each list, it ignores and passes over 3 and continues on the list. However when it encounters 6, stops and doesn't continue due to the error. I tried using try/except. I want my loop to ignore the RuntimeError('NOP') and continue on.

```
INPUT:
for i in z:
    try:
        f(i)
    except RuntimeError:
        pass
OUTPUT:
Processing integer 11
Processing integer 22
Processing integer 33
Processing integer 55
Processing integer 66
Processing integer 87
Processing integer 8
Processing integer 9
Processing integer 10
Done
Processing integer 31
Processing integer 53
Processing integer 54
Processing integer 66
Processing integer 7
Processing integer 8
Processing integer 9
Processing integer 10
Done
Processing integer 2
Processing integer 4
```

The actual output I want is:

```
Processing integer 11
Processing integer 22
Processing integer 33
Processing integer 55
Processing integer 66
Processing integer 87
Processing integer 8
Processing integer 9
Processing integer 10
Done
Processing integer 31
Processing integer 53
Processing integer 54
Processing integer 66
Processing integer 7
Processing integer 8
Processing integer 9
Processing integer 10
Done
Processing integer 2
Processing integer 4
Processing integer 8
Processing integer 10
Processing integer 11
Processing integer 35
```

Any ideas on how to use something similar to "continue" get get past a raised error?

——EDIT——
READ THIS!!

Okay here’s the real issue since it really has nothing to do with the function I created above. Sorry for the long read but it’s necessary.

I created function f as an example to see if I could get past a RunTimeError. This was an attempt to solve a larger problem I have. I have a df of about a million rows and 23 columns. There’s a column for IDs. In reality though there’s only about 18,000 unique ids. So I created a for loop that iterates through each unique ID. Within that loop I create a filtered dataframe with rows/columns for each ID. With that filtered data I’m running a curve fit based on values available in columns and some function I created to calculate exponential decline curve. It’s a simple equation.
http://www.petrocenter.com/reservoir/DCA_theory.htm

Once the curve fit is run, I take the parameters the curve fit solved and plug into my exponential decline curve function. The new values of that function I add as a new column to the dataframe for that unique ID inside the for loop. Then I store each unique IDs dataframe with the new curve fit function data column inside a dictionary. So I can access each IDs data frame that has the original values, and the estimated values based on the curve fit using the exponential decline curve.

Basically I’m curve fitting 18,000 times. through that process, some of the curve fits yield a RunTimeError of not being able to solve the curve fit. I’m okay with not all of them being solved. I don’t have time to check 18,000 unique IDs data to make sure it’s clean enough to curve fit. So I want to be able to skip those ID instances where the RunTimeError shows up and move on to the next unique ID in the for loop.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This is possible but I'm not seeing the benefit?

Comment: Why not just take the raise runtime error out and put a custom error message. The raise condition seems to break the loop and the error message doesn't contribute anything anyway

Comment: If you raise in a for loop, its gonna break it. No way around it unless you try/except inside the first function.

Comment: The problem is the function `f`. It raises an exception and stops the loop right then and there. You can't unring this bell without some heroics. Do you have the ability to change what `f` does? If your test for 6 is just a stand-in for a call that raises the error, you could catch it in f.

Comment: I created function f as an example to see if I could get past a RunTimeError. This was an attempt to solve a larger problem I have. I have a df of about a million rows. There’s a column for IDs with a whole lot of data. In reality though there’s only about 18,000 unique ids. 
So I created a for loop that iterates through each unique ID. Within that loop I create a filtered dataframe with rows/columns for each ID. With that filtered data I’m running a curve fit based on values available in columns and some function I’ve pre determined.....continued....

Comment: Once the curve fit is run, I take the parameters the curve fit solved and plug into my function. The new values of that function I add as a new column to the dataframe for that unique ID inside the for loop. basically I’m curve fitting 18,000 times.  through that process, some of the curve fits yield a RunTimeError because the data for a unique column may not be adequate. I don’t have time to check 18,000 unique IDs data to make sure it’s clean enough to curve fit. So I want to be able to skip those instances where the RunTimeError shows up and move on to the next unique ID in the for loop.

Comment: The link you've provided appears to be broken. "This topic could not be found."

Comment: Added a new link. The link just shows a simple equation for exponential decline. I’m using scipys curve fit to find the decline curve based on each unique IDs oil production in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

The implementation problem is that your error handler must be at the level at which you wish to handle the error.  Your code fails to handle the error within the processing loop.  When your raise the error, your function exits the loop, exits the function, and raises the error for the calling program to handle.  It's too late to continue the loop.

If you want to continue the loop within the function, then you have to handle the exception within the function.  Very simply, you shouldn't be raising an exception at all.  As you've described your desired functionality, there is no difference between case `3` and case `6`.

```
def f(x):
    for i in x:
        if i == 3 or i == 6:
            continue
        
        print(f'Processing integer {i}')
    
    print("Done")
    return
```

---

RESPONSE TO OP's EDIT

I think you've identified the central problem of your post: in your posted code, the loop itself raises the exception; in  your actual example, the loop *calls* a function, and that function raises the exception.  It seems as if the code you need is straightforward, something like this:

```
for row in df:
    try:
        params = fit_function(row)
    exception RuntimeError:
        print(row, " failed to fit.)
        continue   # if there is more row processing for a successful fit.
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please see my updated problem statement to further understand my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're catching, and dealing with the exception in the outside loop only. Your function *f* doesn't have any treatment to the exception you raised. I'm considering that you need to raise an exception, otherwise there's no difference between the `3` and `6`. A second suggestion is to change your function f, to be more atomic, instead of being something that runs over the entire list, you can have a function that tests each element, and raises an exception in case of some condition.

Instead of setting the try-except block in the loop through `z`, use the try-catch in the `f` function. Your code would be something like this:

```
def f(x):
    for i in x:
        try:
            if i==3:
                continue        
            elif i ==6:
                raise RuntimeError('NOP')
            print(f'Processing integer {i}')
        except RuntimeError:
            continue
    
    print("Done")
    return
z=[
    [11, 22, 33, 3, 55, 66, 87, 8, 9, 10],
    [31, 3, 53, 54, 3, 66, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [2,4,6,8,10,11,35]
]
for i in z:
    try:
        f(i)
    except RuntimeError:
        pass
```

------- Code update for the detailed information provided after edition -

```
import pandas as pd
import logging

#Setup logging to a file
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)

#Your fit function
def fit(filtered_df):
     #Your exponential decline fit goes here
     return fit_results

#Reading your dataset
df = pd.read_csv("all_your_data.csv")

#list of dataframes results
fit_results = []
#list of failed_ids
failed_ids = []
for unique_id in df.YOUR_ID_COLUMN.unique():
    try:
        fit_results.append(fit(df[df.YOUR_ID_COLUMN==unique_id]))
    except RuntimeError:
        failed_ids.append(unique_id)
        logging.error("{} curve fit failed".format(unique_id))
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please see my updated problem statement to further understand my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Understood Jay, in that case just follow the concept that I mentioned above. Create a function to fit a unique ID (one of the 18000 you mentioned) and put the try-except clause outside of your call to the fit function. I would recommend adding in the exception section some sort of logging containing the id of the curve that failed. This way you can check for individual failures later, and if your dataset is good enough it would be way less than 18k curves. I hope it helps

Comment: That's pretty neat, could you provide a simple example with code?

Comment: @JayAlmendarez, please see the update for the code sample